# Laravel 5.1 FatalErrorException in RegistersUsers.php line 32

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, fatal-error, user-registration

since a few time I started programming in Laravel for a schoolproject. Now I tried to implement a login system. My database for userinformation is running on my homestead virtual machine, running with Postgresql. I already migrated the tables, so they exist and the database is running. Problem is: When I fill in the registrationform and send it, I get an error:

> FatalErrorException in RegistersUsers.php line 32: Call to a member function fails() on null

You can see the code of RegistersUsers.php underneath:

```
    <?php
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getRegister()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

When I try to log in it gives the warning the log in credentials doesn't exist in the database (because I haven't registered yet), so it seems that the database connection works properly.

Does someone know a solution for this?

**----UPDATE----**

Underneath I added my AuthController is included. You can also see my project on my github, so you can look into my other files if needed: https://github.com/RobbieBakker/LaravelProject56

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    private $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        if(!$validator->fails())
        {
            session(['email' => $data['email']]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue there is with the validator. Please post the contents of the controller that uses the `RegistersUsers` trait (by default it's `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it just by **commenting the function** which called this error. I'm not sure if it's supposed to be solved like that, but my login system seems to work fine now.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot return validator instance from your validator function ))

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
       $validator = Validator::make($data, [
           'name' => 'required|max:255',
           'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
           'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
       ]);

      if(!$validator->fails())
      {
        session(['email' => $data['email']]);
      }

      return $validator;

   }
```

I had same error )

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to "make" the validator.

try changing it to this..

```
    $validator = $this->validator->make($request->all(), $rules);
```

see if that works...

Comment: That's not true here, since `$this->validator($request->all())` should return a validator instance, because by default the `validator` method is defined by the [`AuthController`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php#L49-L56) that ships with Laravel. And that trait is part of the core of the framework which should not be modified.

Comment: if you want to use the ValidatesRequests trait on the controller then you need to pass the Request object and some rules to the "validate" method.

So something like this.. 
`$this->validate($request, $rules);`

I thought you passed in the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` object as a dependency since it was called "validator"

Comment: @Bogdan no where does it say he is using the "AuthController" controller. but you may be right.

Comment: It's true that fact is not stated, that's why I wrote _by default_ in my comment, to take into account the fact that this might not be the case. Either way, for the trait to work, the `validator` method method must return a `Validator` instance, regardless of where the method is defined.

Comment: Thanks for you fast reactions! I added my AuthController to the question, also with a link to github so you can look into my files if you need it for the solution.